# Sending anonymous email from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

This may be a stupid question, but is there any possible way (from a developer's perspective) to send an email from the MFMailComposeViewController and also change the From: address from the default email account set up on the phone? I want to upload some data from my application, but I don't want it to be linked to the user's email address.

Comment: oh, good, more spam on my iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Even if you change the From: it does not accomplish any kind of anonymity. Any well-behaved mail server adds that info to your mail headers.